# getting error finding location of device android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, location, locationlistener

Toast.makeText(this,"location manager started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

```
        Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager. PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        Toast.makeText(this,"location manager worked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"first if",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            double longi = location.getLongitude();
            lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

            textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                    + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);

        } else  if (location1 != null) {
          //  Toast.makeText(this,"second if",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            double latti = location1.getLatitude();
            double longi = location1.getLongitude();
            lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

            textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                    + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);


        } else  if (location2 != null) {
            double latti = location2.getLatitude();
            double longi = location2.getLongitude();
            lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

            textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                    + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(this,"Unble to Trace your location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @mohammadRezaAbiri toast: unable to find location. if conditions not working

Comment: @mohammadRezaAbiri sometimes it return location but mostly it gives "unable to trace your location"